# Can not uninstall java from mac M1

Tags: java, macos

I have the following version of java installed

```java
rahul@doctor ~ % java --version
openjdk 19.0.1 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-21)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10-21, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The place where java is installed

```java
rahul@doctor ~ % which java
/usr/bin/java
rahul@doctor ~ %
```

When tried to delete the java files

```java
rahul@doctor ~ % sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/java
rm: /usr/bin/java: Operation not permitted
```

When tried as a root

```java
rahul@doctor ~ % sudo su
sh-3.2# sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/java
rm: /usr/bin/java: Operation not permitted
```

When tried with brew to delete the java

```java
rahul@doctor ~ % brew uninstall openjdk
Error: No such keg: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk
rahul@doctor ~ % brew uninstall openjdk19
Error: No available formula with the name "openjdk19". Did you mean openjdk, openjdk@11, openjdk@17, openj9 or openjdk@8?
rahul@doctor ~ % brew uninstall openjdk@19
Error: No such keg: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@19
```

While going through some other question, there mentioned to delete `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` but it does not exists in my system

```
rahul@doctor ~ % ls sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
ls: -rf: No such file or directory
ls: rm: No such file or directory
ls: sudo: No such file or directory
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines:
```

Comment: But why are you trying to remove it at all?

Comment: I would like to install jdk 8.

Comment: Currently, i am not able to do so, since older java version is not being deleted.

Comment: This is really problematic for me that i am not able to remove jdk

Comment: Are you aware you can install multiple versions of the Java JDK? Does JDK 8 even have a binary that supports Apple ARM silicon? I personally have doubts Oracle would bother releasing a Apple silicon compatible binary of Java 8

Comment: Multiple versions of jdk can be installed, but the problem is i am not able to remove jdk

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: This was installed a couple of months ago and i don’t remember exactly how did i install it. I might have used homebrew or jdk `.dmg` file as much i can remember.

Comment: @Rahul - Can’t you check history? Does your user have sudo rights?

Comment: If you used brew to install, perhaps you should use brew to uninstall. Do a web search to find some tutorials on that. FYI, in the future, using brew just to install Java is overkill. You can simply download a Mac-specific installer from any of several vendors such as Azul Systems, Adoptium, Amazon, Microsoft, BellSoft, Red Hat, IBM, Oracle, etc.  Or use [*SDKMAN!*](https://sdkman.io/), a bunch of nicely written bash scripts for installing and uninstalling JDKs from your choice of a subset of the JDK vendors mentioned above.

Comment: You can't delete `/usr/bin/java` it is in a protected area. It is just a small program provided by Apple that locates the real Java installation in known locations.

Comment: Try running `/usr/libexec/java_home --verbose` to list the Java installations that macOS knows about.

Comment: 19.0.1 (arm64) "Oracle Corporation" - "OpenJDK 19.0.1" /Users/rahul/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-19.0.1/Contents/Home
    18.0.1.1 (arm64) "Oracle Corporation" - "OpenJDK 18.0.1.1" /Users/rahul/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-18.0.1.1/Contents/Home
    1.8.202.08 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_362 (arm64) "Azul Systems, Inc." - "Zulu 8.68.0.21" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_342 (x86_64) "Amazon" - "Amazon Corretto 8"

Answer (score 0):

The binaries in `/usr/bin/` (e.g. `/usr/bin/java`) are shipped with the macOS instead of being installed by homebrew. They are on the OS's partition which is mounted read-only. Since they are there before you've installed Java, I wouldn't bother removing them. You can just remove the JDK you installed and leave these binaries alone.

If you do really want to remove them checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57440334/sip-is-disabled-but-usr-bin-is-write-protected-anyway-macos-catalina-beta-10/59395264#59395264 to disable SIP and mount the root as writable.

For uninstalling, to determine where you installed the JDK, maybe try to use `/usr/libexec/java_home`.

Comment: `/usr/bin/java` is just a small "hook" that finds the real Java installation, it should never be removed.